# Sort an array as per another array (different lengths) using Comparator results in wrong order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I need to sort an array according to another array, eg:

list1: [221, 54, 50, 138, 125, 145]

list2: [50, 125]

then the sorted list1 should be: [50, 125 ,221, 54, 138, 145]

I tried the following code:

```
Collections.sort(list1, Comparator.comparing(listItem -> list2.indexOf(listItem)));
```

But this results in:  [221, 54, 138, 145, 50, 125]

How can I get the 50 and 125 at the top and the rest after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `list1` element does not contain in `list2` then `indexOf` return `-1` that's why those values come first. So for those value use `list1.size()` then those value will come later.

```
Collections.sort(list1, Comparator.comparing(listItem -> list2.contains(listItem) ? list2.indexOf(listItem): list1.size()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i had  made the question generic but this worked even with sorting an array objects.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting the items of `list1` first is that the index of its elements which are not there in `list2` is returned as `-1` and therefore they are getting placed first. All you need to do is to reverse the order as shown below:

```
list2.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
Collections.sort(list1, Comparator.comparing(listItem -> list2.indexOf(listItem)).reversed());
```

Note that you need to sort `list2` in reverse order before applying the `reversed`. If you do not want to change ordering or `list2`, you can clone `list2` and use it with `Comparator`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(221, 54, 50, 138, 125, 145));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(50, 125));

        // Clone list2
        List<Integer> list2Clone = new ArrayList<>(list2);
        // Sort the cloned list in reverse order
        list2Clone.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

        // Sort list1
        Collections.sort(list1, Comparator.comparing(listItem -> list2Clone.indexOf(listItem)).reversed());

        // Display the result
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[50, 125, 221, 54, 138, 145]
```

Comment: It seems i need to follow up, i made the above example generic, but in my app i need to sort an array of objects, and my old code: `Collections.sort(roomSets, Comparator.comparing(room -> list.indexOf(room.getId())));` worked(resulting in the reverse order). But on adding the reversed() function there `Collections.sort(roomSets, Comparator.comparing(room -> list.indexOf(room.getId())).reversed());`, it suddenly cannot resolve the method at all.(The Id is String). Please let me know if you have an idea why the object behaves like that on adding the reversed function

Comment: @JohnMarkson - I'm busy with some meetings and I'll look into the new requirement once my meetings are over. Just wanted to confirm the new requirement: the solution works for numbers but you want a solution that can work for any type of object (e.g. String or objects of some class) - is it the correct understanding of your requirement? Maybe you can post a new question for a faster response so that other contributors can post some solution before I can look into it after my meetings are over.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for responding even though you are busy, but i got it to work using the other answer in this post itself, the other user suggested using the ternary operator to specify a high index value for the items that don't exist in list2

Comment: That's great! Wish you success!